# How can I fire integration tests separately using failsafe-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I cannot run integration tests, but only unit tests.

Here is my `Maven` config (see code below). It uses two plugins. One of them is `maven-failsafe-plugin` and the second one is `maven-surefire-plugin`.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <skipITs>${skipTests}</skipITs>
    <skipUTs>${skipTests}</skipUTs>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipUTs}</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                <skipITs>${skipITs}</skipITs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I try to run unit tests using this commend

```
mvn clean test
```

And there is the command to start integration tests separately

```
mvn clean failsafe:integration-test verify
```

Result of invocation of the last command is

```
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.16:integration-test (default-cli) @ integration-test-demo ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
```

Comment: Are there suitably named tests, i.e. *IT.java etc. in `src/test/java` folder?

Comment: See [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html).

Comment: @Raghuram I use `src/integration-test/java`, and `java` is a test source folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use profiles for these:

### Properties

```
<properties>
        <!-- Only unit tests are run by default. -->
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
    </properties>
```

### Profiles

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>all-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>all-tests</build.profile.id>
                <!-- All tests are run. -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- Used to locate the profile specific configuration file. -->
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                <!-- Only integration tests are run. -->
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

### maven-surefire-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

### maven-failsafe-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Ensures that both integration-test and verify goals of the Failsafe Maven plugin are executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property is true -->
                        <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The Integration Tests end in ...IntegrationTest.java, and I run the profile that I required (all-tests, integration-tests). The unit tests are run by default.

I am pretty sure that I copied this from somewhere, but now I can not remember the link. Sorry.

Comment: [Similar approach](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/integration-testing-with-maven/), but makes one step further - separate directories for unit and integration tests.

Comment: @Iker And what `surefireArgLine` and `failsafeArgLine` are? Could you show them?

Comment: @Aaron Sorry for that, deleted them and test it if it works. Edited in the asnwer.

Comment: When I run IT tests I get `[INFO] No tests to run.`

Comment: My Maven command `mvn clean failsafe:integration-test` or `mvn clean failsafe:integration-test -P integration-tests`

Comment: I assume that you copied the snippets above in your pom.xml and the names of your integration tests follow these structure --> *IntegrationTest.java, so: 'mvn test -P integration-tests' should run your tests. Does it works?