# Skip unit test but run integartion test with maven

Tags: unit-testing, maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I've a maven project which use surefire plugin for both unit tests and integration tests.
Is there a maven command that I can use just to skip the unit tests but to run integration tests.

I've tried `mvn clean install -DskipUnitTests` but that is not working

Comment: Why not correctly using maven-surefire-plugin for unit tests and maven-failsafe-plugin for integration tests. This separation is causing your problems..

Comment: Do you consider to use Failsafe plugin with the integration tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise Yes I agree. But it take lot of effort since the project contains number of modules

Comment: Sure but it should be separated anyway so just take the chance to cleanup the project. Separation of unit and integration tests is very important. Running unit tests and integration tests separately as you already like to do. This would make life easy.

Answer (score 2):

I would say: no.

But I recommend you the failsafe plugin solution. Some refactoring/renaming, and you can test.

See here my answer, it could help you: [How can I fire integration tests separately using failsafe-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239283/how-can-i-fire-integration-tests-separately-using-failsafe-plugin/27244382#27244382)

Answer (score 1):

run this command:`mvn verify -Dtest=!*Test -DfailIfNoTests=false` 
Below is my pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.aaa</groupId>
  <artifactId>IntegrationTestMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>IntegrationTestMaven</name>
  
  <!-- <properties>
        Only unit tests are run by default.
        <skip.integration.tests>true</skip.integration.tests>
        <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
    </properties>
   -->
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-source</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integrationtest/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                
                <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IT.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <!-- Skips integration tests if the value of skip.integration.tests property is true -->
                        <!-- <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests> -->
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <!-- <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>all-tests</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>all-tests</build.profile.id>
                All tests are run.
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>false</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <properties>
                Used to locate the profile specific configuration file.
                <build.profile.id>integration-test</build.profile.id>
                Only integration tests are run.
                <skip.integration.tests>false</skip.integration.tests>
                <skip.unit.tests>true</skip.unit.tests>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
   -->
</project>
```